# How can I pass the current element to a Javascript function in a Knockout.js binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

So I'm trying to add a class to an element using Knockout.js based on whether a child checkbox is checked or not. To do so, I'm trying to pass `this` as an argument to my function. Currently, my abridged DOM structure is the following:

```
<tr data-bind="css: { selected: isRowChecked(this) }">
    <td><label><input type="checkbox"></label></td>
</tr>
```

An my `isRowChecked` function is this (I'm using jQuery to locate the input):

```
function isRowChecked(elem) {
    var checkbox = $(elem).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    return checkbox.checked;
}
```

Yet, if I `console.log` `elem` all I get is the global window object.

It is not feasible to use jQuery to solve this problem completely as the project I am working in is already using knockout nearly exclusively. Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't use jQuery in your KO viewmodels! You should use the observables and the checked binding instead to track when the checkbox is selected: http://jsfiddle.net/eqoryb6v/

Comment: @nemesv, okay, that's helpful, but I have multiple rows, each with one checkbox. Using your method, when I select one checkbox, *all* the rows and checkboxes are highlighted. http://jsfiddle.net/eqoryb6v/1/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by passing the special binding context variable $element. It's the last variable [discussed here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).

> $element
>
> This is the element DOM object (for virtual elements, it will be the
>   comment DOM object) of the current binding. This can be useful if a
>   binding needs to access an attribute of the current element. Example:

`<div id="item1" data-bind="text: $element.id"></div>`

In your case, that would look like this:

```
<tr data-bind="css: { selected: isRowChecked($element) }">
    <td><label><input type="checkbox"></label></td>
</tr>
```